# What does this formula (from an econometrics textbook) calculate?

Tags: regression, estimation, linear-regression

I have encountered this formula in econometrics book in chapter about regression with 1 independent variable:

$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - b_0 - b_1x_i)^2$

I understand that hat over left part means that it is estimate and $\sigma^{2}$ means variance. But I can't understand estimated variance of what it is.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: This should be a [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) (searching the constants $b_0$ and $b_1$ for a set of points $(x_i,y_i)$ such that the sum is minimal).